Method to offset stroke outline when varying thicknesses by an attribute in ArcGIS Pro

I'm attempting to create an electoral map where an inner glow of the state boundaries vary in thickness by the amount of electoral votes for the 2024 US presidential election. I want a gradient stroke or inner glow that is contained fully within the state boundaries. I know it's easy to offset or donut or add an inner glow when the thicknesses are consistent, but what about when I'm varying the thicknesses based on the electoral votes attribute? Can I control the offset by the thickness of each individual outline?
Is there a way to accomplish this with Arcade expressions? Maybe the offset() function? I would have to know how to select the outline shape as the input and offset it by half the thickness of the current outline width.

Here is the basic approach for you to tweak as needed. It relies on you knowing the minimum and maximum number of votes, something you can easily work out from your dataset. You need to turn on Allow symbol property connections then you can associate many properties to values in fields.

The code in the custom expression is:
var maxvalue = 9000; // Max number of votes
var minvalue = 3000; // Min number of votes
var normvalue = (maxvalue - $feature.votes) / (maxvalue - minvalue); // Scale current vote value between 0 and 1
return normvalue * 10; // return rescaled value and boost by 10 so a 1 would be a 10pt thickness

